# How do i add all the values in my ascending array?

Tags: c++, arrays, conditional-statements

First i need to re-arrange all the values of my array into ascending order then add it afterwards. For example the user input 9 2 6, it will display in ascending order first ( 2 6 9 ) before it will add the sum 2 8 17.. The problem is my ascending order is not working, is there something wrong in my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int numberof_array, value[10], temp;
int i = 0, j;
void input()
{

    cout << "Enter number of array:";
    cin >> numberof_array;
    for (i = 0; i < numberof_array; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter value for array [" << i + 1 << "] - ";
        cin >> value[i];
        cout << endl;

    }
}
void computation()
{

// this is where i'll put all the computation
    for (j = 0; j < numberof_array; j++)
    {
        cout << value[j];
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= numberof_array; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= numberof_array - i; j++)
        {
            if (value[j] > value[j + 1])
            {
                temp = value[j];
                value[j] = value[j + 1];
                value[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
void display()
{
// display all the computation i've got
    cout << "\nData after sorting: ";
    for (j = 0; j < numberof_array; j++)
    {
        cout << value[j];
    }
    getch();
}
int main()
{
    input();
    computation();
    display();
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: If does not produce the desired result, there obviously is something wrong with your code.

Comment: Besides, what's with all those globals, `<conio.h>` and the utterly useless function name `computation`? You need to find better learning material.

Comment: why are you using C style arrays instead of `std::vector<int>`? You could then stop sorting manually and just use`std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());`

Answer (score 0):

```
   void computation(){
    for (int j = 0; j < numberof_array; j++)  cout << value[j]<<"\t";

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberof_array; i++) {
        temp = value[i];
        int temp_idx = i;
        for (int j = i; j < numberof_array; j++) {
            if (value[j] < temp) {
                temp = value[j];
                temp_idx = j;
            }
        }
        int temp_swap = value[i];
        value[i] = value[temp_idx];
        value[temp_idx] = temp_swap;
    }
  }
```

How about changing your second function to something like above.

I have to agree with other commentators that your coding style is not preferred but there might be more to the story than meets the eye.